# Append varible to url or set session

Tags: plugin-development, permalinks, plugins, variables

I just wrote a little plugin that detects if the user is on a mobile browser and if so detects them away from the WordPress site to a mobile (simple) version of part of the site.

As I got to thinking I'm redirecting user who may want to see the full site. I can easily add a check by creating a URL such as `http://example.org?force_web=true` The only problem is my plugin checks the top of each page to see if it's mobile so I would need to set `force_web=true` on all pages.

The other idea would be to use sessions but it seems WordPress doesn't support sessions unless you add `session_start();` to your `wp_config.php` file which I don't want to ask the plugin users to do.

Is this something others have experienced? Is the best way to re-write all permalinks with the addition of my variable?

Open to ideas and suggestions

Comment: why would you need to redirect the user? simply check if he's using a mobile browser and display different content if he is.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. I wanted to extent this functionality to give a link to the full site from the mobile site. The problem is if they were on a mobile device it would just redirect from the main site to the mobile site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ambitious Amoeba said, just do the check on each page load; it shouldn't be that expensive.

Otherwise, another possibility to store a single bit of information would be to use browser cookies.

Comment: Oh Cookies I didn't think of that! Good call.I'll look into that option.

Comment: yes it's months later, but i got around to implementing this and ended up just setting a cookie.

Comment: wow. nice to see you on here BR...